# Implementing Mac style on click of a icon using css,jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, macos, html

I have a logo in `href` eg.`<div class='icon' id='2'><a href=''>logo</a></div>`  ,& if users click on this div id=2 , then a new big div  will open just above of this div.
Basically, I'm wondering to implement the Mac system style using css/jquery. Is this possible>
![enter image description here][1]

Folks! I'm a server side programmer, and very week at GUI using jquery,css. So thought to ask your help here.

Comment: This is called the Genie effect, here are a couple of SO questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659147/javascript-to-minimize-div-using-genie-effect and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575919/genie-animation-javascript

Comment: @stackErr thanks. It will be easier for me if, i can find some example demo online.

Comment: The answers and comments on those questions have some demos.

Comment: @stackErr yeah, i can saw that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have your new `<div>` hidden by default, then use the following jQuery to slide it down:

```
$('#2').click(function(){ $('#newdiv').slideDown(200); });
```